# How to enable multiple input text fields with one checkbox with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have multiple text fields that is disabled by default and I have one checkbox above them. I want that when you check this checkbox it will enable all text fields.

```
**Checkbox** not checked            **Checkbox** checked
**input field** disabled            **input field** enabled
**input field** disabled            **input field** enabled
**input field** disabled            **input field** enabled
**input field** disabled            **input field** enabled
**input field** disabled            **input field** enabled
etc....
```

It need to fit this html structure:

```
<div class="large-4 columns">
   <label for="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">co-applicant</label>

   <div class="large-12 columns">
      <input type="text" id="inputbox" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" placeholder="First name" disabled="disabled">
   </div>
   <div class="large-12 columns">
     <input type="text" id="inputbox" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" placeholder="Last name" disabled="disabled">
   </div>
   <div class="large-12 columns">
     <input type="email" id="inputbox" required placeholder="Email" disabled="disabled">
   </div>
</div>
```

I have looked up several examples but didn't get any of them to work. Also, the jquery code - where should I put it for it to work the best?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#test').click(function() {
    $('input:text').attr('disabled',!(this.checked))
});
```

[**Demo1**](http://jsfiddle.net/FArMm/771/)

Update for `Email` type:

In case if you are using different `type`',Select with `input`

```
$('#test').click(function() {
    $('input').attr('disabled',!(this.checked))
});
```

[**Demo2**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshbm13/FArMm/772/)

Comment: Nice use of `!(this.checked)`! Avoids having to use `if($(this).is(':checked'))` or some variation of that.

Comment: @Dom `Write less, Do more slogan everywhere` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#checkbox').click(function() { 
        $(".inputbox").prop("disabled",false);

});
```

"inputbox" is make it as class.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ablealias/RaK3D/)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that it needed to be a class! I tried your answer but that didn't work. But I changed my own try of it for taking the input class instead and now it worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#checkbox').click(function() { 
        $("input:text").prop("disabled",false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**You must have [unique ID's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18453687/2256325)**. You can change all your multiple IDs to Classes instead.

Try this:

```
$('#checkbox').on('change', function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $(this).closest('div').find('input').removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

### Demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/UKzvp/)**

**Or,** if you want to go by class (by changing your `ID`'s to `Class` like in my demo under):

```
$('#checkbox').on('change', function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $(this).closest('div').find('.inputbox').removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

Demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/UKzvp/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! Changed the input id to be a class instead.

```
<div class="large-4 columns">
   <label for="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">co-applicant</label>

   <div class="large-12 columns">
      <input type="text" class="inputbox" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" placeholder="First name" disabled="disabled">
   </div>
   <div class="large-12 columns">
     <input type="text" class="inputbox" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" placeholder="Last name" disabled="disabled">
   </div>
   <div class="large-12 columns">
     <input type="email" class="inputbox" required placeholder="Email" disabled="disabled">
   </div>
</div>
```

And the jquery:

```
<script>
 $('#checkbox').change(function() {
      $('.inputbox').attr('disabled',!this.checked);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Great! You can accept one answer and vote up the answers you think were useful.